# OAuth 2.0 client ID, I need the Redirect URIs to be "web-server" in my client ID

Tags: php, url, oauth, google-analytics

Problems creating a client ID, I need to deploy a web application that will use google analytics api. This web application will be on a local path such as this

`http://web-server/example/example`

Problem is the Redirect URIs for the client ID needs to be localhost or a www. etc

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from Dyna Dns.

http://dyn.com/dns/

This will give your local computer a hostname accessible from anywhere.
It works even for non-static IPs.

Answer (score 0):

Most OAuth 2.0 providers will support fully-qualified hostnames, even if they aren't publicly accessible.

So, for instance, your local machine name can be:

```
http://johny-smith/
```

But is also accessible as:

```
http://johny-smith.corp.company.com
```

or

```
http://johny-smith.internal.company.com
```

etc

If you're on a linux box, try typing 'hostname' to get your fully-qualified domain name (FQDN).